# Python: My directory is not giving individual value output

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I have created a code that imports data via .xlrd in two directories in Python.

### Code:

```
import xlrd

#category.clear()
#term.clear()

book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\Koen\Google Drive\etc...etc..")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

num_rows = sheet.nrows

for i in range(1,num_rows,1):
    category = {i:( sheet.cell_value(i, 0))}
    term = {i:( sheet.cell_value(i, 1))}
```

---

When I open one of the two directories (category or term), it will present me with a list of values.

> > print(category[i])
> >     So far, so good.

However, when I try to open an individual value

> > print(category["2"])
> >     , it will consistently give me an error>>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile", line 15, in <module>
    print(category["2"])
KeyError: '2'
```

The key's are indeed numbered (as determined by i).
I've already tried to []{}""'', etc etc. Nothing works.

As I need those values later on in the code, I would like to know what the cause of the key-error is.

Thanks in advance for taking a look!

Comment: That code is illegible. There is a toolbar button for formatting as code. Please use that and the preview below the edit window to make sure you get everything right.

Comment: Noted! It's my first post, so I will look at it more closely next time.

Comment: @KoenSmits I edited it for you. In future, copy/paste a whole block of code and while it's highlighted, click the `{}` button in the editor or use Ctrl + k.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are reassigning category and term in every iteration of the for loop, this way the dictionary will always have one key at each iteration, finishing with the last index, so if our sheet have 100 lines, the dict will only have the key `99`. To overcome this, you need to define the dictionary outside the loop and assign the keys inside the loop, like following:

```
category = {}
term = {}
for i in range(1, num_rows, 1):
    category[i] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    term[i] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
```

And second, the way you are defining the keys using the `for i in range(1, num_rows, 1):`, they are integers, so you have to access the dictionary keys like so `category[1]`. To use string keys you need to cast them with `category[str(i)]` for example.

I hope have clarifying the problem.